# Mongoose populate query return all results with skip/limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following method in a little node/express app :

```
async getAll(req, res) {
    const movies = await movieModel
        .find()
        .populate({path: 'genres', select: 'name'})
        .skip(0)
        .limit(15);
    return res.send(movies);
};
```

With the following schema :

```
const MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    externalId: { required: true, type: Number },
    title: { required: true, type: String },
    genres: [{ ref: "Genre", type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }],
    releaseDate: {type: Date},
    originalLanguage: {type : String},
    originalTitle: {type : String},
    posterPath: {type : String},
    backdropPath: {type : String},
    overview: {type: String},
    comments: [{ ref: "Comment", type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }],
    votes: [VoteSchema]
}, {timestamps: true}
});

MovieSchema.virtual("averageNote").get(function () {
    let avg = 0;
    if (this.votes.length == 0) {
        return '-';
    }
    this.votes.forEach(vote => {
        avg += vote.note;
    });
    avg = avg / this.votes.length;
    return avg.toFixed(2);
});

MovieSchema.set("toJSON", {
    transform: (doc, ret) => {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.__v;
    },
    virtuals: true,
    getters: true
});
```

However the query always return all document entries.
I also tried to add `exec()` at the end of the query or with `.populate({path: 'genres', select: 'name', options: {skip: 0, limit: 15} })` but without result.

I tried on an other schema which is simpler and `skip`/`limit` worked just fine, so issue probably comes from my schema but I can't figure out where the problem is.

I also tried with the virtual field commented but still, `limit` and `sort` where not used.

My guess is that it's comes from `votes: [VoteSchema]` since it's the first time I use this, but it was recommanded by my teacher as using `ref` 
isn't recommended in a non relational database. Furthermore, in order to calculate the averageNote as a virtual field, I have no other choice.

EDIT : just tried it back with `votes: [{ ref: "Vote", type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }]` And I still can't `limit` nor `skip`

Node version : 10.15.1

MongoDB version : 4.0.6

Mongoose version : 5.3.1

Let me know if I should add any other informations

Comment: What are you only trying to return 15 of? Is it the Movies? Or is it the Genres within the movies?

Comment: I am only trying to return 15 Movies, usually movies have at max 4 Genres, but you are rigth, I misunderstood the option in the populate

Comment: You would not be alone in misunderstanding populate.Presumably the `limit(15)` just works if the `populate()` is not there at all. Try that just to test, and then try `.find().limit(15).populate('genres', 'name').exec()` which I suspect due to the way mongoose internals slightly mangle things would be okay.

Comment: Indeed, I just tried and it works. Thank you very much sir. If you mind writing an answer I'll accept it. Also I didn't know about the populate syntax you mentionned, is it the equivalent of passing an object with path and select or somehow different ? I am also curious as to why the `exec()` must be used but I might have to read the docs more thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually more about how `.populate()` actually works and why the order of *"chained methods"* here is important. But in brief:

```
const movies = await movieModel
  .find()
  .skip(0)
  .limit(15)
  .populate({path: 'genres', select: 'name'}) // alternately .populate('genres','name')
  .exec()
```

The problem is that `.populate()` really just runs another query to the database to *"emulate"* a *join*. This is not really anything to do with the original `.find()` since all `populate()` does is takes the *results* from the query and uses certain values to *"look up"* documents in another collection, using that other query. Importantly the *results* come **last**.

The `.skip()` and `.limit()` on the other had are *cursor modifiers* and directly part of the underlying MongoDB driver. These *belong* to the `.find()` and as such these need to be in *sequence*

The MongoDB driver part of the builder is is forgiving in that:

```
.find().limit(15).skip(0)
```

is also acceptable due to the way the options pass in *"all at once"*, however it's *good practice* to think of it as `skip` **then** `limit` in that order.

Overall, the `populate()` method *must* be the ***last*** thing on the chain after any *cursor modifiers* such as `limit()` or `skip()`.

Comment: Thank you, I could have lost hours trying to figure that out by myself. Just one more question, why is the `.exec()` method used ? I just tried without it and the result is the same.